# Extract previous day observation from xts object in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have time-series data of three days, formatted as `xts` object. The dummy data is generated as:

```
library(xts)
Sys.setenv(TZ="Asia/Kolkata")
seq <- timeBasedSeq('2015-06-01/2015-06-03 23')
z <- xts(1:length(seq),seq)
```

Now, using the index of any third day observation, I want to extract previous day observation at the same time instant. Accordingly, I coded it as

```
a <- z[50]  # Any observation of third day will suffice
b <- as.Date(index(a), tz ="Asia/Kolkata")-1  #previous day date
z[.indexDate(z) %in% b & .indexhour(z) %in% .indexhour(a)]
```

The last command results in

```
                    [,1]
2015-06-03 01:00:00   50
```

But, It should result into

```
                    [,1]
2015-06-02 01:00:00   26
```

Can anyone point where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.indexDate` is defined as `.index(x) %/% 86400L`, and `.index` returns the number of seconds since the origin in UTC.  As you did when you constructed `b`, you need to account for the timezone when converting to Date:

```
d <- as.Date(index(z), tz ="Asia/Kolkata")
z[d %in% b & .indexhour(z) %in% .indexhour(a)]
#                     [,1]
# 2015-06-02 01:00:00   26
```